# Check if a binary tree has a path equal to the given sum

Tags: c, binary-tree, computer-science

I'm having an issue figuring out the solution for this problem:

"Given a binary tree (each node has an int value), and a sum, return 1 if the tree has a path equal to the given sum (from a node to a leaf, doesn't have to be the root), else return 0".

I've done a similar question, where the path has to start from the root.
But here, the question states that the path can start anywhere, as long as it ends with a leaf..

Tried searching online for a solution, but I found some that are only working by using the buffer.

Is there any possible solution for this, without the buffer?

Thanks in advance!

(Prefer in C,C++ syntax or even a pseudo code ^.^``)

This was my first try:

```
int hasPathSum(Tree tr, int sum){
return hasPathSumRec(tr.root, sum, 0);
}


int hasPathSumRec(TNode* node, int sum, int current){

int num1, num2;
current += node->data;
if (current > sum)
    current = 0;

if (node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL){
    if (current == sum)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
else if (node->left == NULL){
    return hasPathSumRec(node->right, sum, current);

}
else if (node->right == NULL){
    return hasPathSumRec(node->left, sum, current);
}
else{
    num1=hasPathSumRec(node->left, sum, current);
    num2=hasPathSumRec(node->right, sum, current);

    if (num1 > 0 || num2 > 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
}
```

and this was the second: (but it doesn't go through all of the nodes, so it's not good..)

```
int hasPathSum(Tree tr, int sum){
return hasPathSumRec(tr.root, sum, 0);
}

int hasPathSumRec(TNode* node, int sum, int current){
int num, num1, num2;


num = node->data;
current = num + current;

if (current > sum)
    current = num;


if (node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL){
    if (node->data == sum || current == sum)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
else if (node->left == NULL){
    num2 = node->right->data;
    if (current + num2 > sum)
        return hasPathSumRec(node->right, sum, num);

    else
        return hasPathSumRec(node->right, sum, current);

}
else if (node->right == NULL){
    num1 = node->left->data;
    if (current + num1 > sum)
        return hasPathSumRec(node->left, sum, num);
    else
        return hasPathSumRec(node->left, sum, current);

}
else{
    num1 = node->left->data;
    num2 = node->right->data;
    /LEFT SIDE--------------------------------------------------/
    if (current + num1 > sum)
        num2 = hasPathSumRec(node->left, sum, num);
    else
        num2 = hasPathSumRec(node->left, sum, current);
    /RIGHT SIDE--------------------------------------------------/
    if (current + num2 > sum)
        num1 = hasPathSumRec(node->right, sum,num);
    else
        num1 = hasPathSumRec(node->right, sum, current);


    if (num1 > 0 || num2 > 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some of your C, C++ or even a pseudo code that you have already tried?

Comment: Added it to the original post

Comment: @Martin Remember to check if the answer is ok and mark it as accepted if it is, or comment on why it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned, you compute the sum of a tree values as the sum of the sums of its subtrees plus the root value. It's clear that as soon as you can compute the sum of this tree you have computed the sums of all its subtrees. So the only thing left to do is adding a check if the sum is equal to the required one **and return it**. Here you can find an implementation for this idea and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which you should have provided in the first place, saving people (me) the effort to write one.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct _TNode {
    int data;
    struct _TNode *left, *right;
} TNode;

typedef struct {
    TNode *root;
} Tree;

typedef struct {
    int sum;
    bool found;
} hasPathSumRec_t;

hasPathSumRec_t hasPathSumRec(TNode* node, int sum)
{
    hasPathSumRec_t ret = { 0, false };
    if (!node)
        return ret;

    hasPathSumRec_t ret_left = hasPathSumRec(node->left, sum);
    hasPathSumRec_t ret_right = hasPathSumRec(node->right, sum);

    ret.sum = ret_left.sum + ret_right.sum + node->data;
    ret.found = ret_left.found || ret_right.found || ret.sum == sum;
    return ret;
}

int hasPathSum(Tree tr, int sum) {
    return hasPathSumRec(tr.root, sum).found;
}

int main(void)
{
    /*
    1 / 2 / 3 / *
      |   |   \ *
      |   \ 5 / * 
      |       \ *
      \ 4 / 6 / 7 / *
          |   |   \ *
          |   \ *
          \ 8 / *
              \ 9 / *
                  \ *
    */

    TNode n[] = {
        { 1, n + 4 - 1, n + 2 - 1 },
        { 2, n + 5 - 1, n + 3 - 1 },
        { 3, NULL, NULL },
        { 4, n + 8 - 1, n + 6 - 1 },
        { 5, NULL, NULL },
        { 6, NULL, n + 7 - 1 },
        { 7, NULL, NULL },
        { 8, n + 9 - 1, NULL },
        { 9, NULL, NULL },
    };

    Tree t = { n };

    int tests[] = { 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 17 };
    size_t ntests = sizeof tests / sizeof *tests;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ntests; ++i)
        printf("%i - %i\n", tests[i], hasPathSum(t, tests[i]));
}
```

Further improvements could allow an early exit if sum is found or exceeded.

Comment: Yes, the solution is working, haven't done a recursion with a returning struct for a binary tree yet so I wasn't even close to this haha, thank you very much!

Comment: @Martin: just for completeness, as an exercise, you can solve the problem without returning a struct. Use a pointer to something argument and manage the recursion correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> > I've done a similar question, where the path has to start from the root. But here, the question states that the path can start anywhere, as long as it ends with a leaf..Is there any possible solution for this, without the buffer?

If you already have a solution with root node, then isn't it just one more recursion required.

Assume your root-node based solution is called IsPathHasSum(root). This will return 1 if sum of nodes on any path from root to leaf matchs given sum. This function should only find paths from root to leaf and not intermediate paths starting from arbitrary nodes.

Now to cover all nodes,

```
-> Start with IsPathHasSum(root), if return value = 1, program terminates
-> If not, invoke IsPathHasSum(root->left). This ignore the root and right tree. 
-> If not, invoke IsPathHasSum(root->right). This ignores root and left tree
```

This can be invoked recursively to start from each node of the tree down to the leaf. If at any point, the return value is 1, program terminates. This re-traversal on same paths again and again is required since your requirement is not to have any buffers.